# Keyence camera video capture in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, ip-camera

I'm making a program for keyence cv-x camera and im really new to this. I'm really struggling to make it capture what its looking at and putting the view into some picture box or something.
Can somebody please help me, because I'm really anxious about it. Right now i did this.

namespace CVXCommunication
{
public class Program
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
// Cesta pro ukládání snímků kamery
private string savePath = @"C:\KameraSnimky";

```
        // Časový interval mezi snímky
        private int captureInterval = 10000; // 10 sekund

        // Instance třídy pro ovládání kamery
        private CVX camera;
        private object logTextBox;

        private void startButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Inicializace kamery
            camera = new CVX();

            // Zapnutí kamery
            camera.SetRunMode();


            // Spuštění periodického snímání a ukládání snímků
            var timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            timer.Interval = captureInterval;
            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(CaptureImage);
            timer.Start();
        }

        private void CaptureImage(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Získání aktuálního snímku z kamery
            var image = camera.CaptureImage();

            // Uložení snímku do knihovny
            var fileName = $"{savePath}image_{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff")}.jpg";
            File.WriteAllBytes(fileName, image);

            // Přidání logu o úspěšném uložení snímku
            logTextBox.AppendText($"Snímek {fileName} úspěšně uložen.\n");
        }
    }
```

Comment: "IP-camera" does not actually give much information. Most network based industrial cameras I know of uses the gige vision (genicam) protocol. Keyence seem to use some analog or proprietary protocol, so you will likely have a harder time getting third party help.

Comment: Most IP cameras support standard protocols like TCP or UDP. This is usually specified in the connection string for the camera such as "udp://192.168.0.105".  If your camera supports a common protocol and you know the connection
 string, you can receive, display and record its video stream using the Multimedia controls from LEADTOOLS SDK as explained in [this help topic](https://leadtools.com/help/sdk/v21/dh/multimedia/to/source-filename-syntax.html).
 If you'd like to try that, the SDK has a [free evaluation here.](https://leadtools.com/downloads). Disclosure: I work for the SDK's
 vendor.